# Use the result of an ajax request as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to know how I can use the result of an ajax request as an "object". I'll try to explain. I have an ajax request that get a number, every 2 seconds, to an xml file. Then I render it into my html.

Here is my js:

```
   var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
   var id = url[3];

setInterval(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://myxml",
       success: parseXml
   });
 }, 2000);

function parseXml(xml){
   $(xml).find("user").each(function() {

           if($(this).attr("id") === id ) {
               $(".DubScore").html($(this).attr("count"))
           }
       });
}
```

and my html:

```
 <div class="DubScore"> </div>
```

It works find, I have a count displayed to my page.

What I want to do, is to take this number and be able to do whatever I wan't with it in my html. For example, name it "Score", and be able to do  "Score" + 2 , and things like that.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the attribute value and store it in a global variable :

```
var score;

function parseXml(xml){
   $(xml).find("user").each(function() {
           if($(this).attr("id") === id ) {
               score = parseInt($(this).attr("count"), 10);
           }
       });
}
```

Afterwards, you may do, for example,

```
score += 2;
$(".DubScore").html(score);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. But what is the 10 for?

Comment: When I add $(".DubScore").html(score); to my js, nothing appears in my html. The count does not appear as it did when I had $(".DubScore").html(score); inside my function